# Is it possible to create a link or button that will launch the link in incognito / private mode?

Tags: incognito-mode

I suspect this is not possible without an extension, but thought it was worth asking.

The scenario: You're providing support/services to users who use a device with a  browsing history that may be covertly monitored by a family member. This can put the user in danger.

Is there a way to provide an option to launch links to those services (clearly labelled and explained) into an incognito window so they won't appear in that user's history?

- Obviously they can manually do it themselves, but that requires knowledge and forethought
- They can clear their cache, but that can raise unwanted attention too.

Fingers crossed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible on a webpage but it is with an extension as there are many privacy concerns if a webpage can open tabs in incognito / private mode

Comment: Thanks @Jeffrey. I suspected that would be the case.